# ¿Que significa este error "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile" tiene solucion?

Tags: java

Cree un programa en java y entonces queria ver si funcionaba asi que intente abrirlo y me sale este error , si tiene solucion diganmelo por favor y si pueden expliquenme que significa eso y porque sucede.

```
public class CalcularAreaDeUnCiculo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int radius = 3;
        System.out.print1n("el radio del circulo es " + radius); /* * Area del circulo es pi * r * r es r el radio. */
        double area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
        System.out.print1n("area es " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Ddla12. Por favor indica cómo creaste el jar, esto es, incluir los comandos o pasos que seguiste para crear dicho jar.

Comment: además explica como estás intentando "abrir" el jar porfavor

Comment: esperen un momento

Comment: lo intento abrir desde la terminal

Comment: `public class CalcularAreaDeUnCiculo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
     int radius = 3;
     System.out.print1n("el radio del circulo es " + radius);
     
     /*
      * Area del circulo es pi * r * r es r el radio.
      */
      
      double area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
      
      System.out.print1n("area es " + area) ;
      
      }
  }`

Comment: ese el codigo del programa

Comment: verifique que estaba en el directorio correcto y si lo estuve , entonces escribi en la terminal : java -jar prueba.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que parece es que estas intentado ejecutar un archivo `jar` pero seguramente tu compilación solo genero el archivo `.class`

Debes cambiar `java -jar prueba.jar` por `java prueba`

Comment: no me funciona escribi java prueba y nada

Comment: no me funciona me dice : `Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal prueba`

Comment: Ya me funcionó amigo gracias ya vi el error